# Brezis' exercise 8.31.2: if $\int_I f=0$ then $\|u\|_{L^2(I)} \leq \frac{1}{(1+\pi^2)} \|f\|_{L^2(I)}$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, sturm-liouville

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 1)$.
I am trying to solve a problem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> **Exercise 8.31** Consider the Sturm-Liouville operator $A u=-u^{\prime \prime}+u$ on $I$ with Neumann boundary condition $u' (0) = u' (1)=0$.
>
> 1. Compute the eigenvalues of $A$ and the corresponding eigenfunctions.
> 2. Given $f \in L^2 (I)$ with $\int_I f=0$, let $u$ be the weak solution of
>    $$
>    (1) \quad
>    \begin{cases}
>    -u'' + u = f \quad \text {on} \quad I, \\
>    u'(0)=u'(1)=0.
>    \end{cases}
>    $$
>    Prove that
>    $$
>    \|u\|_{L^2(I)} \leq \frac{1}{(1+\pi^2)} \|f\|_{L^2(I)} .
>    $$

I am trying to solve question (2.). In below attempt, I get the inequality with a bigger constant and have not utilized $\int_I f=0$. Could you elaborate on how to obtain the desired constant $\frac{1}{\left(1+\pi^2\right)}$?

---

It follows from (1) that
$$
\int_I [ -u''v + uv ] = \int_I f v,
\quad \forall v \in H^2(I),
$$
which (by integration by parts) implies
$$
\int_I [ u'v' + uv ] = \int_I f v,
\quad \forall v \in H^2(I),
$$

Substituting $v=u$, we get
$$
\int_I |u|^2 \le \int_I fu,
$$
which (by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) implies the desired inequality.

Comment: The problem gave a hint no? [Apply Question 6 in Problem 49].

Comment: @CheeHan I would like to see if there is a more direct approach without appealing to Question 6 of Problem 49.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly the corresponding eigen-problem
$$
\begin{cases}
-u'' + u = \lambda u\quad \text {on} \quad I, \\
u'(0)=u'(1)=0,
\end{cases} \tag{*}
$$
has eigenvalues $\lambda_n=(n\pi)^2+1$ with the corresponding eigen-functions $u_n=\cos(n\pi t)$, $n=0,1,2,\cdots$. Observe
$$\int_Iu_n=\int_Iu_mu_n=0 \text{ for }m\neq n,\int_Iu_n^2=\frac12, m,n=1,2,3,\cdots.$$
Integrating (1) and using $\int_If=0$, one has
$$ \int_Iu=0 $$
and hence one has to rule out the eigenvalue $1$. Let
$$ u=\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n\cos(n\pi t), f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n\cos(n\pi t)$$
in (1). Then
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty((n\pi)^2+1) u_n\cos(n\pi t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n\cos(n\pi t)$$
and hence
$$ ((n\pi)^2+1) u_n=f_n\text{ or }u_n=\frac{f_n}{(n\pi)^2+1}. $$
So
$$ \|u\|^2_{L^2}= \frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty|u_n|^2=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{((n\pi)^2+1)^2}|f_n|^2\le \frac12\frac1{(\pi^2+1)^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty|f_n|^2=\frac1{(\pi^2+1)^2}\|f\|_{L^2}^2 $$
which gives the desired the estimate.